# Pass sed output as if it's file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have ruby script that receives name of config file as argument.
I need to run it in loop changing some param inside the config each iteration.

Everything ok with sed, however I have no idea how can I pass the sed's script output to ruby, so that ruby will think that it's file? Is it possible?

It might be clearer with code:

That is how it's usually launched:

```
ruby script.rb config.conf
```

What I want is:

```
sed 's/one_param/another_param/' config.conf | ruby script.rb ???????
```

What should I put so that ruby script were think that it received file with content as sed's output?
I thought about workaround with saving temporary file as sed's output and then passing the file to script.rb, but I sure there is better way to achieve it

Comment: try `ruby script.rb  <$(sed 's/one_param/another_param/' config.conf)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/171095/how-do-i-join-two-named-pipes-into-single-input-stream-in-linux) on how to use *process substitution*.

In short:

```
cat <( echo "yo")
```

Or in your case:

```
ruby script.rb <(sed 's/one_param/another_param/' config.conf)
```

To create a *process substitution* you enclose the command with `<(...)` like: `<(COMMAND)`

Check  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution

Comment: It's not a named pipe but a _process substitution_. Named pipe require `mkfifo`

Comment: @sputnick Thanks. I actually learned this today off StackOVerflow. I can't find the post I found this in, but I'm sure this is how it was called there :) It is also how it's referenced in the question I linked to.

Comment: In fact, *Process substitution* creates a pipe: `file <(echo)`. But I agree the formal term is *Process substitution*.

Answer (score 0):

Conventionally, UNIX programs accept `-` as a filename to mean "read from standard input":

```
echo foo | wc -
```

This is a convention that works basically everywhere.

However, script writers who don't know Unix may not think to implement this. This is a bug that should be fixed by them, but you can work around it using `/dev/stdin` instead:

```
echo foo | wc /dev/stdin
```

In your example, this would be one of

```
sed 's/one_param/another_param/' config.conf | ruby script.rb -
sed 's/one_param/another_param/' config.conf | ruby script.rb /dev/stdin
```